# Cox hazards model and test for trend

Tags: r, trend

If I have a cox proportional hazards model with as a predictor of event a categorical variable (and other covariates such as age etc), let's say for example the categorial variable I am interested in is tumor size which can be 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 for example, and I see there is a trend towards an higher HR of death with the increasing in tumor size, how can I compute in r and get a p?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of danger in accepting your incomplete specification since you could have a size classification that will mess this up, as for example: 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-80, 80-120, 120-240. 
Unless you have carefully constructed your factor to have correctly ordered ascending levels, what I am about to suggest as a shortcut will fail.

```
 survmdl <- coxph(Surv(tie,event) ~ as.numeric(fact), data=dat)
```

You will get a "test of trend" which would be interpreted as the per-category increase in the log(Hazard) for rising size and it would be a single coefficient. So post your actual factor levels if you wnat a better considered reply.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply! I divided the variable (serum hormone level) in quartiles and then also tried to divide it in 10 ng/ml categories (and in this last case I get 7 levels)...

Comment: I'm unclear from your comment whether this was sufficient information, and I note that you did not accept the answer, so is there further comment needed? If so, then you need to edit you question to include much more detail (and R code).